# Change LSApplicationQueriesSchemes at Runtime

Tags: ios, plist, enterprise

A friend asked me to find a way to change the plist property LSApplicationQueriesSchemes from within the iOS app itself to added new schema url at runtime. The app is distributed with an Enterprise account. I told him this is impossible for me, but I don't find anything about it to provide an evidence. Could someone provide me some useful information (e.g. a link) to support my thought?

Comment: It's not possible. This is a measure Apple explicitly added to prevent developers from abusing `canOpenURL` to figure out what apps users had installed. Certain company was misusing this method - even updating their list dynamically - and as such Apple decided that your app should try to open other apps that it has defined at development time. Even if you did find a way around this, Apple would most definitely fix it in the next release and break the app from that point onwards. Furthermore, the Info.plist is in your App Bundle, which is read-only.

Comment: @AndyIbanez Please make your comment an Answer so the Question can be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible. This is a measure Apple explicitly added to prevent developers from abusing `canOpenURL` to figure out what apps users had installed. Certain company was misusing this method - even updating their list dynamically - to learn what apps users had and installed and because of this Apple decided that your app should try to open other apps that it has defined at development time only. Even if you did find a way around this, Apple would most definitely fix it in the next release and break the app from that point onwards. Furthermore, the Info.plist is in your App Bundle, which is read-only.